# Call to undefined method stdClass::restore() on restoring soft delete

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to restore softdeleted data but I just keep getting this error
[Call to undefined method stdClass::restore()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/butH8.png)

My routes look like this

```
    Route::resource('/dvd', 'DvdController');
    Route:get('dvd/{id}/restore', 'DvdController@restore');
```

And this is my controller

```
    public function restore($id)
{
    //Dvd::withTrashed()->where('id','=',Input::get('id'))->restore();
    //Dvd::find($id)->restore();
    $dvds = DB::table('dvds')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $dvds->restore($id);
    $view = redirect('dvd')->with('message', 'Data berhasil di-restore');
    return $view;
}
```

I call the method from a button

```
    <a style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block" 
    href="{{ URL('dvd/' . $data->id . '/restore') }}">Restore</a>
```

I don't know what i'm getting wrong, i'm a very newbie on PHP and laravel, please include the right code.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using DB facade, so you get an StdClass instance as a result, not an Eloquent model and restore() is a method on Eloquent class.

You need to change:

```
$dvds = DB::table('dvds')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

To something like:

```
$dvds = Dvd::withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->first();
```

And then it should work fine.